# アクションバーのホームボタンのロゴが表示されない

Tags: android, android-support-library

アクションバーにあるホームボタンのロゴを表示しようとしているのですが、ロゴが表示されません。
まずManifestファイルをいじってみたのですが、変化なしです。

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:logo="@drawable/icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

コード側でgetSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icon)としても何の変化もありません。
ホームボタンのアイコンを表示するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
何か他に必要な設定があるのでしょうか？
ちなみに現在の端末のバージョンは4.1.2です。

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()` との記述があるためSupport Libraryを使っていると思われますが、Support Libraryを使っていることを書いておくことで回答が集まりやすくなるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、これからはタグ付け機能も活用したいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローは投稿したあとの編集も可能です。いつでも投稿を改善することができますので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ちなみに、Android 4系以降と2.x系のいずれにおいてもロゴが変わらないのでしょうか？変わらないことを確認したAndroidのバージョン等も書いていただくと回答をする上での参考になります。

Comment: はい、了解しました。使用しているAndroidのバージョンを投稿内容に追記しました。

Comment: ロゴが変わらないとのことでしたので、すでにランチャーアイコンが表示されていたものだと思っていました。そもそも表示されていなかったという認識でよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: はい、ロゴ自体が表示されておりませんでした。

Comment: 表示されないとのことでしたので、それが分かるよう修正いたしました。

Comment: すみません、お手数をおかけします。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity`のアクションバーにロゴを出すというのであれば、

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

で表示されるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ホームボタンのロゴが変わりました！
getSupportActionBarのメソッドには似たような名前が多いので少し注意しないといけないですね。何はともあれありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

ToolBarでしか使ったこと無いので回答外しているかもですが、`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)`を呼ぶ必要がある気がします。

https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(boolean)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)を呼んだところ、ホームボタンのアイコンに変化がありませんでした。。。

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

ではどうでしょうか。

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。setIconもためしてみたのですが、やはりホームボタンのロゴは変わりませんでした。。。